# Returning generated keys in MySql with JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

I'm programming with plain [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) a [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) layer because I only have  **61.38 MB** on *Java Memory* in my *Tomcat* (service hosting). I have a table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in MySQL. The current implementation has no problems. But I would like to know the value that was generated in the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

The current code looks as follows in the method that inserts a new row.

```
public Integer store(MyBean bean) throws DAOException {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT ...");
        if (bean.getSomeProperty() != null) {
            ps.setShort(1, bean.getSomeProperty());
        } else {
            ps.setNull(1, Types.SMALLINT);
        }

        /* Other fields */

        int rows = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (rows == 1) {
            // RETURN the generated value
        }
        return null;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOException(e);
    } finally {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have seen that this is possible in **`Hibernate`**, but because I have little memory, is not a feasible option.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Using the JDBC concept of `getGeneratedKeys()`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id.html#connector-j-examples-autoincrement-getgeneratedkeys
- Or use the MySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id.html#connector-j-examples-autoincrement-select